# How do I validate a required property of an optional key in Joi?

Tags: joi

I have the following Typescript schema:

```
export interface LiveDate {
  production: string,
  test?: string
}

interface Widget {
  name: string,
  path: string
}

interface Manifest {
  livedate?: LiveDate,
  'trusted-types'?: string[],
  widgets?: Widget[]
}
```

And the following Joi schema:

```
const liveDateSchema: Joi.ObjectSchema = Joi.object<LiveDate>().keys({
  production: Joi.date().iso().required(),
  test: Joi.date().iso().optional()
})

const widgetSchema: Joi.ObjectSchema<Widget> = Joi.object<Widget>().keys({
  name: Joi.string().required(),
  path: Joi.string().required()
})

const manifestSchema: Joi.ObjectSchema<Manifest> = Joi.object<Manifest>().keys({
  'livedate': liveDateSchema.optional(),
  'trusted-types': Joi.string().optional(),
  'widgets': Joi.array().items(widgetSchema).optional()
})
```

I'm not quite fully grokking how to set up [the conditional logic](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#anywhencondition-options) (with apologies that this is a versioned link) here such that if `livedate` is present, then Joi should validate that `livedate.production` is an ISO date string.  As it currently stands, if I set `livedate.production` to `not a date string` my test still passes and I think this is due to `livedate` being marked as `optional` in my `manifestSchema` object so it's not doing the date validation.

Comment: `.optional()` should not check the children when the object itself (livedate) is missing, but when it is present, it will validate the children (production, test). Can you provide the example value you are passing for `production`?

Comment: @RvyPandey appreciate the ping, I would have neglected to post anything further.  I've added my "answer" which confirms what you said in that what I have is correct.  I've noted in my answer the accidental issue I was seeing that I was not able to get to the bottom of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I have is correct.  Here is the Jest test:

```
  it('should fail validation if livedate.production is present but not an ISO-8601 date', () => {
    const manifest: Manifest = {
      livedate: {
        production: 'not an ISO date string'
      }
    }
    const outputLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'test-directory')

    expect(() => createManifest(manifest, outputLocation)).toThrowError(getISODateErrorMessage('livedate.production'))
  })
```

Where `getISODateErrorMessage` is just a utility to return the Joi error message.

I was seeing issues when I was calling `.toThrowError('')` (while still building that test) in that the test was passing, but should not have been.  I was not able to to track that down as the error return from `schema.validate` was correct and non-empty.